# process.env.key is showing the actual api key in source code

Tags: dapps, nodejs, external-api, dotenv

In my js file I am using:
const apikey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

In the .env file I have:
REACT_APP_API_KEY = 123456789

Everything is working fine BUT, when I start (npm run start) and then go into source code, there is:
const apikey = 123456789;

That means, instead of showing process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY in source doe to hide the key, it is showing the actual api key.

Comment: For general questions about programing and other frameworks it is better to ask directly in stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use plain React with `create-react-app`.

`REACT_APP_` environment variables in `create-react-app` need to be added during build time, are included in the static bundle and are public.

As also mentioned in their docs:

***WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app!
Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.***

Link to the `create-react-app` docs article:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

You should consider using secrets on your server, not your client. In case you would use a full-stack framework like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) utilizing React, you can write server and client code in one application (in which only your backend touches your secrets).